# Bi color led with tri-state pin (high->D1, tri-state->D2, low->off)

Tags: led

I have a tri-state pin and I would like to use a bi-color led:

```
Pin     Low     High    Hi-Z
D1      off     on      off
D2      off     off     on
```

There are a lot of examples around but none in the combination of the above table.

How can I do that with minimum components?

Comment: Why would you care which state is which as long as you get all three states? The normal of is high z both leds off.

Comment: Because this is how the chip (a battery charger) is behaving. I'm interested to signal the Hi-Z. And when the pin is low, both leds need to be off

Comment: So your attempting to replicate the functionality of an existing ic? Or circuit? You need to post those details, part numbers or pictures.

Comment: What is the Voh (output HIGH voltage) of the pin, and at what current draw?

Comment: How is the bi-color LED wired internally - common Anode, common Cathode, or back-to-back?

Comment: Ie is it 2 pins or 3?

Comment: what is the manufacturer and part number of the device that has the tri-state pin ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a 3-pin LED common anode it can be done as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsddkA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
.

If it's acceptable to have both LEDs on for a high input (which would give you
red + yellow or green + yellow for a red/green LED) you can reduce it to just 
two components total (plus the LED) by using a prebiased array for Q1/Q2, a resistor array for R3/R4 and eliminate Q3/R5.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzYKRr.png)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Specification:

```
    IN    L1    L2
1.  L     0     0
2.  H     1     0
3.  X     0     1
```

[image]

*Figure 1. A totally bonkers method of obtaining the required LED logic.*

How it works:

1. With IN low U1 turns on and L1 is shorted out turning off. U2 is off so L2 is off too.
2. With IN high, U1 turns off so L1 lights and L2 is off.
3. With IN tri-stated, both U1 and U2 turn on. L1 is shorted out and L2 turns on.

Notes:

- R1 and 2 have to be low enough to turn both U1 and U2 on in tri-state. The current in the opto-LEDs has to be fairly high to get enough through the photo-transistors. Read up on "current transfer ratio" to learn more.
- R3 will pass current all the time.

I haven't tried it and it isn't efficient but I think it meets the user requirement specifications.

Answer (score 0):

### Splitting rails for fun and for profit

The basic approach we take here is similar to Cleary/Sheridan/Thomson's work in [US Pat. 6133753](https://www.google.com/patents/US6133753) -- we use a bias generator to weakly pull the output to the half-supply point, then evaluate the voltages that result.  The main difference here (and why the claims of the patent cited wouldn't read on what we're doing here) is that we don't care about power consumption nearly as deeply as the patentees do, so we can dispense with the sampling complexity they claimed and employed.

A simple voltage divider suffices to bias the output weakly to the half-supply mark, while from there, we can then use a few bog-standard BJTs and some diode trickery to handle the voltage sensing.  Note that this requires a 4-pin bi-color LED (i.e. one where the LED chips have no pins in common).  This configuration isn't seen in through-hole parts, but is reasonably common in SMT bicolor LEDs -- for prototyping purposes, simply use two separate LEDs instead.  Also note that this is intended for a 5V supply -- for a higher supply voltage, change R3 and R4 as appropriate to keep the LED currents reasonable, and change D2 to a Zener to set the threshold for Q3 turning on above the half supply mark.  (This approach won't work well with lower supplies though -- you'll want to use comparator hijinks instead of Q3's arrangement in that case, as we run out of supply margin there.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGPnNv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: While this works, it seems overly complex compared to the simpler 2 resistor option for high z = off circuit. What's the benefit?